# Walking a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I am using jQuery to inject values from an JSON object into an existing, empty table.

What I want to do is fill up my table top-to-bottom, instead of what it does now - left to right. So how would I modify this snippet to accomplish what I want?

```
_.each(dataset, function(v, k){
    $("tr td:empty:first", "#myTable tbody").html("<strong>"+v+"</strong>");
});
```

I guess that It would be possible to target the td in the column which has the fewest filled rows, but how?

Comment: What does `dataset` contain exactly?

Comment: `dataset` contains properties, `var dataset = {"key": "value"...}`

Comment: Yes, that obvious, but what's not clear is what exactly you are outputting and in which order. To do what you want you need to loop over the table rows such a fredrik shows, but that requires to access the data elements in an order (or by index), but the properties of objects in JavaScript are unordered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your selector to:

```
$("tr td:empty:first:first-child", "#myTable tbody")
```

So that it matches only when the table cell is the first-child of it's parent, the row, so will only insert in the first column.

---

Edit: A method to populate the table based on a known and limited number of columns

It works by selecting each table column using the `nth-child` of each row, then concatenating the columns together, and filtering for the first empty one.

```
var cells = [].concat(
    $('tr td:nth-child(1)').get(),
    $('tr td:nth-child(2)').get(),
    $('tr td:nth-child(3)').get(),
    $('tr td:nth-child(4)').get()
)
_.each(dataset, function(v, k){
  $(cells).filter(':empty:first').html("<strong>"+v+"</strong>");
});
```

---

Edit: Generic version

```
// create array to hold cells ordered by column
var cells = [];
// loop through desired columns adding to cells array
// hint: you can specify column `from` and `to` in the for loop definition
for(i=1;i<=4;i++)
  cells = cells.concat($('tr td:nth-child('+i+')').get());

// loop through the data, populating each column in order
_.each(dataset, function(v, k){
  $(cells).filter(':empty:first').html("<strong>"+v+"</strong>");
});
```

Comment: That's close, but it only targets the first column in my table, but leaves the other columns untouched. Any ideas?

Comment: I have updated the answer to do exactly what you need, and added a generic implementation. I think I will be adding this function to my library.

Comment: That's a much cleaner solution than I would ever be able to create. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Is `dataset` an array? If so, something like this:

```
var self;
$('#myTable tr:has("td:empty")', function (index, elem) {
    if (index < dataset.length) {
        self = $(this);
        self.find('td:empty').html("<strong>"+dataset[i]+"</strong>")
    }
});
```

..fredrik

Comment: `dataset` is an object as mentioned. I converted it to an array with `jQuery.makeArray()` but couldn't get it working with your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up doing, using `underscore.js` to iterate the dataset:

```
var currentCol = 0;
var currentRow = 0;
var renderedCount = 0;

_.each(dataset, function(v, k) { 

    /* Switch to a new column when we have rendered enough (4)
     * elements vertically per column and reset the rowcounter.
     */
    if (renderedCount % 4 === 0) {
        currentCol++;
        currentRow = 0;
    }

    // Inject our value as HTML into the first empty TD per column
    $("tr:eq("+currentRow+") td:empty:first", "#mytable tbody").html(v);

    // Increment current row count and our renderedCount 
    currentRow++;
    renderedCount++;
});
```

Many thanks to [@BillyMoon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/665261/billy-moon) for helping out!

**Update:**
To create the empty table before doing the above, I did this:

```
// To allow repeating strings (n) times. Borrowed from someone on SO
String.prototype.repeat = function( num ) {
    return new Array( num + 1 ).join( this );
}

// Setup our wanted maximum amount of columns horizontally and our table structure
var maxColsPerRow = 4;
var rowHTML = "<tr>"+'<td></td>'.repeat(maxColsPerRow)+"</tr>";
var datasetCount = _.keys(dataset).length; // Amount of properties in our dataset calculated with underscore.js keys()-method.

// Append as many empty rows&cells to our table that we'll need 
$("#myTable tbody").html( rowHTML.repeat( Math.round( datasetCount/maxColsPerRow));
```

Comment: This is an interesting problem. I would still like to have a solution that can apply to any person with the same requirement. I would prefer a method that does not need pre-knowledge of the table/data size. Please update your answer if you ever solve this.

Comment: I agree with that. Updated my post to show how I did the table rendering. It should be easy to make it a bit more flexible and self-adjusting to larger datasets where more rows/columns are needed, altough I am happy with it as it is!